# Error: El valor no puede ser nulo. Nombre del parametro: String

Tags: c#, .net, webservice, vba

Estoy desde en una aplicación de Visual Basic 6 tratando de consumir una dll (creada en .net) que realiza una llamada a un servicio.

A la hora de consumir esta dll en otro programa de .net NO me surgen errores, y me devuelve los valores. Sin embargo cuando la quiero consumir en visual basic me sale este error:

> ```
> "Error: El valor no puede ser nulo. Nombre del parametro: String"
> ```

El código de la dll en .net es asi:

```
public class ConsultaClienteCaller
{

    public string BuscarClientePorProducto(ulong CodigoSubsistema, String IdProducto)
    {

        String IdPersona = string.Empty;

        ConsultaCliente.ConsultaCliente ConCliente = new 
        ConsultaCliente.ConsultaCliente();


        try
        {

            ConsultaCliente.BuscarClientePorProductoRequest Request = new ConsultaCliente.BuscarClientePorProductoRequest();
            List<Cliente> ListClientes = new List<Cliente>();

            #region Header
            #endregion

            #region Datos
            #endregion

            #region Respuesta
            return IdPersona;
            #endregion

        }
        catch (Exception errors)
        {
            throw errors;

        }

    }
}
```

El código en la aplicacion de VBA 6 es:

```
Dim ConsultaCliente As TCRM_TCO_NV.ConsultaClienteCaller
Set ConsultaCliente = CreateObject("TCRM_TCO_NV.ConsultaClienteCaller")
Dim IdPersona As String
Dim IdProducto As String
Dim Codigo As Long
IdProducto = "0000000000002"
Codigo = 85



IdPersona = ConsultaCliente.BuscarClientePorProducto(Codigo, IdProducto)
```

En esta última línea es donde aparece el error. No se a que se puede deber esto. PD: Quiero aclarar que la dll esta registrada para interoperabilidad COM.

UPDATE (para el que lo necesite)
El problema fue resuelto. Lo que sucedía es que le pasábamos parámetros del header (para hacer la llamada al ws) a través de un archivo .config y si bien cuando ejecutabamos la aplicacion los levantaba sin problema, cuando lo debugueabamos nos salia este error. Lo resolvimos incluyendo el mismo archivo config bajo el nombre vb6.exe.config en la carpeta: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\vb6.exe.config

Answer (score 0):

Debes indicar al compilador cómo exponer la clase hacia el exterior. Para conseguirlo debes utilizar ciertos atributos especiales que provienen de **System.Runtime.InteropServices**

- Todas las clases e interfaces de COM deben identificarse de manera única para evitar conflictos. Para ello se utilian GUIDs, que son identificadores universales. Debes generar uno para cada interfaz y clase y asignárselos.
- Además le estamos diciendo que esa interfaz debe ser visible para COM. Si no le ponemos explícitamente este atributo ConVisible no se exportará y tendremos un problema.
- ClassInterface: que indica el tipo de interfaz de clase que se debe generar para COM. En este caso indicamos el valor None porque la interfaz necesaria la hemos generado nosotros ya.
- ProgID: este es un atributo clave ya que determina la manera en la que vamos a instanciar esta clase desde COM cuando hacemos early binding, es decir, desde un entorno de scripting.
- Una última cosa que debemos hacer es asignarle identificadores en la interfaz a los diferentes métodos que tengamos (no así a las propiedades) para que se identifiquen de manera única y podamos utilizarlas, para lo cual se usa el atributo DispId. Este atributo toma un número único que puedes ser cualquiera.

Lo siento por el tocho teórico es Copy Paste para explicarte las cosas... a mi me dieron una clase y una interfaz y me dijeron así se hace. Prefería ponerte una explicación de para que sirve cada cosa aunque ni yo lo sabia ;)

```
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace TCRM_TCO_NV
    {
        [Guid("5DC9CA23-F02D-4FE4-8423-C97B3F7B7A95")]
        [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
        [ComVisible(true)]
        [ProgId("TCRM_TCO_NV.ConsultaClienteCaller")]
    public class ConsultaClienteCaller : IConsultaClienteCaller
    {

        public string BuscarClientePorProducto(ulong CodigoSubsistema, string IdProducto)
        {

            return CodigoSubsistema + IdProducto;

        }


    }

}
```

Debido al funcionamiento interno de COM, toda la funcionalidad que vayas a exponer hacia el exterior deberás hacerlo a través de interfaces de programación.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TCRM_TCO_NV
{
    [Guid("86C4BBCD-08D4-46E7-8366-3277601D017E")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IConsultaClienteCaller
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        string BuscarClientePorProducto(ulong CodigoSubsistema, string IdProducto);
    }
}
```